# First Derivative / Maximisation Problem

Tags: optimization, derivative

It appears to be super easy, but I just cannot reconcile how Lambert et al. (2012) on page 8 come from (3) to (4) - please see screenshot! Particularly bothering: where does the "Lambda" in the denominator come from? Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks a lot for all your support!

[image: Screenshot Lambert 2012 p. 8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of the given objective (utility) function $U$ with respect to $D_I$ is

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dU}{dD_I} & = -\lambda D_I + (E[\tilde{V}|\Phi_I] - p_0 - \lambda D_I) - \frac{1}{r_I \Pi_I}D_I \\
& = (E[\tilde{V}|\Phi_I] - p_0 - \lambda D_I) - D_I\left(\frac{1}{r_I \Pi_I} + \lambda \right)
\end{align}$$

You should be able to take it from here. Personally I'd be more wary of phrases like "an informed investor chooses $D_I$ to maximise [some arcane expression]". Assumptions like these are like the spherical cows of economics....